# Client assembly

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Can anyone please tell me what is 'Client Assembly'. And why do we use it.

I am new on AX. Kindly help me understanding the things. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on [Deploying Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg889192.aspx).

Also see your answer here: http://dynamicsuser.net/forums/p/51904/268304.aspx